# How to split pytorch dataset with respect to labels?

Tags: pytorch, dataset

I need to split the CIFAR10 dataset by category so that I can create a smaller sample with the same number of samples for each category.

How can I best accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
sorted_by_value = [0]*10
for i in range(10):
  sorted_by_value[i] =(train.data[numpy.where(numpy.array(train.targets) == i)])
  numpy.random.shuffle(sorted_by_value[i])
```

For any dataset, you can just replace 10, with the number of categories, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [torch.utils.data.Subset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) for that purpose. Here's an example of how to make a subset of the [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) training set containing only the numbers 0 through 4:

```py
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
trainset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)

classes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
indices = [i for i, (e, c) in enumerate(trainset) if c in classes]
trainset = torch.utils.data.Subset(trainset, indices)
```